# Selecting multiple elements with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

I have this piece of code:

```
var requiredFields = el.querySelectorAll("input[required]:not(:disabled):not([readonly]):not([type=hidden])");
```

If I want to add the `textarea` and `select` to the query I'm ending up with this:

```
var requiredFields = el.querySelectorAll("input[required]:not(:disabled):not([readonly]):not([type=hidden])"+  
",select[required]:not(:disabled):not([readonly]):not([type=hidden])"+
",textarea[required]:not(:disabled):not([readonly]):not([type=hidden])");
```

My feeling says this could be better.. but how?

Bonus: Please give me a good resource for querySelectorAll function.

Comment: FYI, select and textarea elements don't have any type attribute.

Comment: What is the var `el`?

Comment: @ShadowWizard You are right, CopyPasta leftovers. @Kevin `el` = document.body.

Comment: You can just select them all and perform the check for required/disabled/readonly when iterating over the elements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Shadow Wizard said, at a minimum you can remove the unnecessary `:not([type=hidden])` in the various places it has no meaning (`select` and `textarea`).

I don't see a problem with the result:

```
var requiredFields = el.querySelectorAll(
    "input[required]:not(:disabled):not([readonly]):not([type=hidden])" +  
    ",select[required]:not(:disabled):not([readonly])"+
    ",textarea[required]:not(:disabled):not([readonly])");
```

...not least because it hands the whole thing off to the selector engine to take advantage of any optimization it can do.

Alternately you could give all of the relevant inputs a common class and then use:

```
var requiredFields = el.querySelectorAll(
    ".the-class[required]:not(:disabled):not([readonly]):not([type=hidden])");
```

...but I'm not sure it buys you much.

> Please give me a good resource for querySelectorAll function.

There's [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) is also usually a good place for this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll)

---

```
window.l = ['input','textarea','select'];
function myQuerySelectorAll() {
    q = '';
    t = '[required]:not(:disabled):not([readonly]):not([type=hidden])';
    l.forEach(function(e) {
        q += e;
        q += t;
        q += ',';
    });
    console.log(q)
}
```

---

```
$> myQuerySelectorAll();
$> input[required]:not(:disabled):not([readonly]):not([type=hidden]),textarea[required]:not(:disabled):not([readonly]):not([type=hidden]),select[required]:not(:disabled):not([readonly]):not([type=hidden]),
```